# Update Contentful entry with a link to a reference filed (in Contentful)

Tags: xcode, swiftui, contentful

I want to update a field on an entry that is a link to another entry inside Contentful (they call it 'Reference'). However they don't have any clear documentation on how to call the data using SwiftUI. I just need to know how to format that API call when using the Contentful Management API. Didn't get any help from the Contentful team nor in their Slack community, so I'm trying here.

The specific entry in question will be the episodes variable which is linked to [HPtvSeriesEpisodes]. No matter what format I try I get the error **"Cannot convert value of type '[Entry]' to expected argument type '[HPtvSeriesEpisodes]"**

I just want to know how should I format that specific line of code

This is my Data Model

```
struct HPtvSeries: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var seriesTitle: String
    var seriesDescription: String
    var seriesDate: String
    var seriesType: String
    var numberofEpisodes: Int
    var seriesBanner: URL
    var seriesThumbnail: URL
    var episodes: [HPtvSeriesEpisodes]
    
    
    
    }
```

The Content Management API call

```
class HPtvSeriesStore: ObservableObject{

@Published var hptvSermons: [HPtvSeries] = []



init(){
    
    
    getArray(id: "hPtvSeries") { (items) in
        items.forEach { (item) in
            self.hptvSermons.append(HPtvSeries(
                seriesTitle: item.fields["seriesTitle"] as! String,
                seriesDescription: item.fields["seriesDescription"] as! String,
                seriesDate: item.fields["seriesDate"] as! String ,
                seriesType: item.fields["seriesType"] as! String ,
                numberofEpisodes:item.fields["numberOfEpisodes"] as! Int,
                seriesBanner: item.fields.linkedAsset(at: "seriesBanner")?.url ?? URL(string: "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/kqmc8c2i3banhhi/HPtv%20Logo_2.png?dl=0")!,
                seriesThumbnail: item.fields.linkedAsset(at: "seriesThumbnail")?.url ?? URL(string: "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/kqmc8c2i3banhhi/HPtv%20Logo_2.png?dl=0")!,
                // episodes: item.fields.linkedEntries(at: "episode") // Not sure how to format the code here
                
            ))
        
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is obvious from the error that the data has been decoded such that the episodes have been decoded as type `Entry`, and you are trying to put them into an `[HPtvSeriesEpisodes]`. However, you didn't provide either of those type definitions, so there is not much more we can say.

Comment: Hey Kevon, I attempted to help you debug this in the Contentful Community Slack :)